# Bash wildcard not expanding hidden files

Tags: bash, wildcards

I'm trying to make a bash script that deals with every file in a directory. All of those file names begin with a dot, so they're hidden. When I try to use a wildcard to grab everything in the directory, the wildcard isn't expanding.

My code that loops over it looks like this right now:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s extglob

for i in "$(pwd)"/*; do
  echo "$i"
done
```

The output is just `/Users/.../*`. The wildcard doesn't expand.

This is different than some of the other threads because it deals with hidden files specifically. If I add a file like `test` to the directory, then it works. I get `/Users/.../test`.

I tried running this in the terminal by itself as well and got the same result. How do I get the wildcard to expand for hidden files?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured it out! Looking more closely at the [documentation for shopt](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html), there's an option called `dotglob` that can be used to include filenames that begin with a dot!

I added `shopt -s dotglob` to the beginning of my script and it works now. The output now lists every hidden file and directory (except `./` and `../`).

My script now looks like this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s extglob
shopt -s dotglob

for i in "$(pwd)"/*; do
  echo "$i"
done
```

Comment: Also useful: `shopt -s nullglob` makes a globbing expression expand to nothing if it matches nothing; "$PWD" holds the same value printed by `pwd`, but `echo "$PWD"` lets you save a fork compared to `echo "$(pwd)"` - in Bash, command substitution is performed using a child process.

Comment: @fra-san, `$(pwd)` (as opposed to `$PWD`) also doesn't work properly when the path to the current working directory ends in newline characters.

Comment: Note that `extglob` is not necessary here for the expansion of that glob. `extglob` would b e needed if you wanted to use the extended ksh88 operators like `@(...)`, `!(...)`, `*(...)`...

Answer (score 2):

posix workaround without dotglob

```
#!/bin/sh

for i in "$PWD"/* "$PWD"/.*
  do
    [ "${i##*/}" = . ] || \
    [ "${i##*/}" = .. ] || \
    [ "${i##*/}" = \* ] || \
    [ "${i##*/}" = .\* ] && continue

    echo "$i"
done
```